# Is it possible to record simultaneously using MIC, CAMCORDER and the accelerometer?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm trying to access three sensors simultaneously. I need the accelerometer data to detect if the person is running, walking or standing still and  MIC and CAMERAMIC data as input to an adaptive filter.

I tried to use threads, one thread for each sensor, but they don't really work in parallel.

```
//declaring 3 threads
public class firstMicThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        isRecording = true;
        Log.i("Thread 1 ", "first thread started" + String.valueOf(isRecording));
        startRecording(audiosource);

    }
}
public class secondMicThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        isRecording = true;
        Log.i("Thread 2 ", "second thread started" + String.valueOf(isRecording));
        startRecording(audiosource2);

    }
}
public class accelerometerThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        isRecording = true;
        Log.i("Thread 3 ", "acceletometer started " + String.valueOf(isRecording));
       // onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener( RecordandStore.this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL );
        Log.i("Thread 3 ", "acceletometer listener registered" + String.valueOf(isRecording));
    }
}
```

and

```
 private View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_startrec: {
                if (checkpermissionfromdevice()) {
                    Log.i("Start click:", "permissions true");

                    // first mic
                    Runnable firstmicR = new firstMicThread();
                    Thread firstmicthread = new Thread( firstmicR);
                    // second mic
                    Runnable secondmicR = new secondMicThread();
                    Thread secondmicthread = new Thread( secondmicR);
                    // accelerometer
                    Runnable acceletometerR = new accelerometerThread();
                    Thread accelerometerthread = new Thread(acceletometerR);

                    firstmicthread.start();
                    secondmicthread.start();
                    accelerometerthread.start();
                    startrec.setEnabled(false);
                    stoprec.setEnabled(true);}
                else { // if check permissionfordevice == false
                    requestPermission();
                }
                break;}
```

Comment: Did you try to use different services?

Comment: No, I didn't consider that option, I will try and let you know. I was trying to make it work with threads because it works with one microphone and the accelerometer (acquisition more or less simultaneous, even if  I don't understand how to control the sampling frequency  of the accelerometer), but it doesn't work at all when I add the second microphone.